# How to control an running instance of Windows Media Center?

Tags: c#, client-server, windows-media-center

How to control a running instance of Windows Media Center?

I have a server-client application, and the server needs to be able to give commands to the client, and then the client has to control Windows Media Center.
I know how to do it with sending Keystrokes, but I don't really want to do that. The best option would be a sort of SDK of API to control Windows Media Center.

For example, when the server sends "Play music - genre trance", then the client application controls the Media Center to start playing trance music.

I'm aware of this question, but it is unclear to me.
[Remote controlling Windows Media Center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703946/remote-controlling-windows-media-center)

So should I make 2 applications for the client side? One Add-in for WMC, and one (the client) that controls that Add-in?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a great post there. Check out this video for a phone implementation - think of the phone as the server app here. It's a bit older but maybe will give you some info.

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Control-Windows-Media-Center-using-a-Windows-Mobile-5-Device

With that said I have no experience here - simply trying to help out : )

Comment: This looks very promising. I searched google alot for anwers, but I never found this link. Thank you very much, I will try it, and will post back when I succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Windows Media SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb189066.aspx)? [Download here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5995) and dig into the [Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb189476.aspx)... I think you'll find some workable options.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I already checked it out. I think this could be helpfull, but at start I was lost in all the options and didn't found a good section of the Programming Guide. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb189819.aspx